# BIRT Reports are not closing the connection after running the reports?

Tags: database-connection, tomcat7, jndi, birt

We are using BIRT Reports in our spring, spring MVC based web application. We have 2-3 reports in our app.

One of them uses BIRT chart and other two are very simple listing reports. All of then use multiple datasets for i/p parameters.

e.g. Report 1 is using i/p params like Division, Product etc which are drop downs and are coming from the database. They are configured as the datasets in the BIRT report.

Whenever I run reports, they work properly for first few attempts. Afterwards it becomes very slow and then it doesn't work at all. It seems that the connections opened by BIRT reports are not being closed.

We are using tomcat as the app server and jndi datasource to connect to the database in BIRT report.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Birt has fixed the bug. What version of Birt are you using?